# Count number of taps with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a button that increases a quantity, and when I tap it, I make a service call. The problem is that if I tap it multiple times I only want to make the service call after I finish tapping it. I tried using a UITapGestureRecognizer but I don't know how to count the number of taps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the sample code

```
- (void)quantityChanged:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {
    static NSUInteger numberOfTaps;
    if (tapRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
       numberOfTaps = 0;
    }
    if (tapRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        NSLog(@"%d",numberOfTaps);
    if (tapRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
        numberOfTaps++;
```

}

Comment: sounds a bit like a strange idea for a user interface - but maybe I didn't get it. Do you want a button where the user taps on (quickly) and if there's no other tap for a while it takes the number of taps and calls some other method with the tap count as param?

Comment: Yeah, the point is that I don't want to make the web service call on every tap, but count the number of taps, and change the quantity accordingly when I make the web service call.

Comment: @Cosmin Exactly my use case too. I ended up using the    performSelector:withObject:afterDelay and    cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I found the solution to my problem. I will perform my web service call with a delay of 0.5 seconds, and each time I press on my button I cancel all the selectors that are waiting to be performed and a call again performSelector: withDelay.

Answer (score 4):

Four possible solutions

I think Your method is fine

```
- (void)quantityChanged:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {

    static NSUInteger numberOfTaps;


   if (tapRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        numberOfTaps ++;

        NSLog(@"web service call with %d",numberOfTaps);
    }

}
```

see the log

```
web service call with 1
web service call with 2
web service call with 3
web service call with 4
```

or

Remove the quantityChanged UITapGestureRecognizer after triggered it one's

I mean , remove the UITapGestureRecognizer from the sender object (inside the quantityChanged method after your first web-service)

Then Add UITapGestureRecognizer to the sender  again after u got the first web-service response.

or

Use UILongPressGestureRecognizer . It's is a long event process. Please check the event state either its started,completed etc and write your code.

```
- (IBAction)longPressDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {        

    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

        NSLog(@"Long press began");

    } else if ( gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized ) {

            NSLog(@"Long press UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized");
    }
    else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        NSLog(@"Long press Ended");
    }
    else {

        NSLog(@"Long press detected.");
    }       
}
```

or

Set the **numberOfTapsRequired** for UITapGestureRecognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(beginComicTransitions:)] autorelease];    
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
doubleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

Comment: You didn't understand my questions. I want to count the number of taps on my UIButton. Using what you said only triggers my selector if the button is tapped at least two times. That's not what I need.

Comment: please describe well the sentence "The problem is that if I tap it multiple times I only want to make the service call after I finish tapping it.". then we can help you.. any sample code.. ?

Comment: Yeah, the point is that I don't want to make the web service call on every tap, but count the number of taps, and change the quantity accordingly when I make the web service call.

Comment: so you mean,quantity is a parameter of ur web service call? i mean when tapping first - web service call with 1 ,when tapping second - web service call with 2 etc ??

Comment: Yes, so in order to make the web service call only once, I want to count the number of taps and make the call only when the taps "ended
"

Comment: or do u want to call the  web service only once at a time ? then sending the second web service only after getting the first web-service response ?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I doubt that this will lead to a practical user interface ... If you have an idea of a maximum count the user can "put in", you could go with several tap gesture listeners which you make dependent of each other with `- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer` ([doc here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer)).

The code could look like this:

```
-(void)addGestureRecognizers
{
  int maxCount = 10;
  UITapGestureRecognizer *other = nil;
  for(int i = maxCount; i < 0; i--)
  {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    tapper.numberOfTapsRequired = i;
    if(other)
    {
      [tapper requireGestureRecognizerToFail:other]; 
    }
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
    other = tapper;
  }
}

-(void)tapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapper
{
  [self callWebservice:tapper.numberOfTapsRequired];
}
```

I didn't test it, never worked with that, but that's what I understood from the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Without a UITapGestureOrganizer it's even easier.

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(multipleTap(_:event:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDownRepeat)
```

And then:

```
func multipleTap(_ sender: UIButton, event: UIEvent) {
    let touch: UITouch = event.allTouches!.first!
    if touch.tapCount == 3 {
        print("triple tap")
    }
}
```